# How do I sum the values in one column depending on the values of 4 other columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a rainfall dataset like the one give below,

```
StationIndex    Station Year    Month   Day Rainfall
1                Dhaka   1970     1       1   1
1                Dhaka   1970     1       2   1
2                Mumbai  1970     1       1   1
2                Mumbai  1970     1       2   1
3                London  1970     1       1   1
3                London  1970     1       2   1
4                NY      1970     1       1   1
4                NY      1970     1       2   1
```

I want to sum the values under the rainfall column according to day, month, year and station (or station index). Basically, calculate the total monthly rainfall for each month of each station throughout the years, and put that in another column. So the output would be like this

```
StationIndex    Station Year    Month   Day Rainfall   Total-Rainfall
1                Dhaka   1970     1       1   1               2
1                Dhaka   1970     1       2   1               2
2                Mumbai  1970     1       1   1               2
2                Mumbai  1970     1       2   1               2
3                London  1970     1       1   1               2
3                London  1970     1       2   1               2
4                NY      1970     1       1   1               2
4                NY      1970     1       2   1               2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a **Table** with `structured references`, but you can change that to regular addressing if you prefer:

*(eg: [Station] refers to that entire column of data in the table $B$2:$B$9; [@Station] refers to the entry in that column on the same line as the formula)*

```
=SUMIFS([Rainfall],[Station],[@Station],[Year],[@Year],[Month],[@Month])
```

[image]

***Note:** You can add `StationIndex` as a criteria, or replace `Station` with `StationIndex` if necessary to properly separate the data.*

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying :D 
Do I just copy and paste the formula to a cell under the new column total rainfall or do I modify this code based of column ranges? When I try to just copy and paste I get an error saying there is a problem with the formula, i should add an ' in front. In other words excel doesn't think this is a problem. I figure you used table with structured reference. How do I do that?

Comment: wait i figured it out by googling i just select the range and make it a table in the data tab. thanks, I will let you know how good it works. i have a total of 1.5 million data rows in excel so might take a while

Comment: @CatVI Excel doesn't have that many rows. How is your data structured?

Comment: it is a time series dataset of daily rainfall data from 1970 to 2019. and it has that many rows in my file so...?

Comment: @CatVU An excel worksheet has only a nillion rows. Where are your other half million rows?

Comment: https://github.com/TheCatWalk/precipitation_prediction_using_bdlstm_in_bangladesh/blob/main/rainfall%20records%20of%20bangladesh%201970-2019.csv this is the file

Comment: @CatVI That makes more sense. That file is only about 580,000 rows, well within the Excel's maximum row specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the formula =sum(F2:F3) [for example] you can select the block of two days in each month, or extend to multiple days, but it is not clear why you would want the total to appear for each row, rather than once for each month.  If that's necessary, you could use a trivial formula like =G1 for the in between rows.

A little harder would be to figure out a general formula for each month where the number of rows varies, that might take some coding.

Comment: I see, I am not really familiar with excel that's why the code was what I needed. Thanks for giving an initial idea anyways. I googled related stuff and another person gave just the answer I needed below.